# Simpler way to retrieve Data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My current firebase database structure:

```
allEvents
  eventId
    title: eventA
    startTime
    prizeIdC
    status:scheduled
  eventId
    title: eventB
    startTime
    prizeIdB
    status: active
  eventId
    title: eventC
    startTime
    prizeIdB
    status: expired
activeEvents
  eventId
    title: eventB
    startTime
    prizeIdB
    status: active
expiredEvents
  eventId
    title: eventC
    startTime
    prizeIdB
    status: expired
Prizes
  prizeIdA
    title: prizeA
    image
  prizeIdB
    title: prizeB
    image
  prizeIdC
    title: prizeC
    image
```

I show one set of users the active and expired events. I successfully can retrieve active and expired event data by setting listeners on "activeEvents" and "expiredEvents". However, since prizes can be edited independently from events I thought to just include the prizeId in each Event data. But now I'm running into problems as I want to set a listener on the prize data linked to the event. I attempted to solve this by iterating over the snapshot.val() and generating an array of prizeIds and then iterate over those prizeIds and set listeners for each i.e

```
const prizeRef = `prizes/${prizeId}`
database.ref(prizeRef).on('value')
```

However, this is turning into a convoluted  process as I am now using async.map to iterate over the prizeId array to set listeners and retrieve prizeData. There has to be simpler solution to my problem/need.

Comment: Need some more info; you want to 'set a listener on the prize data linked to the event'. Do you mean you want to be notified if a prize changes; i.e. prizeIdA is currently 'prizeA' so you want to know if it's changed to 'A NEW CAR!'? Or you want to know if the prize associated with an event changes to a different prize that already exists in the Prizes node?

Comment: So you want to get all prizes for expired or active events?